# Connecting Itunes Connect To Code For GameCenter Leaderboard

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have used the code below to create my GameCenter page in my app. However, I haven't been able to connect the leaderboard that I created on iTunes Connect to my code, so the app just produces a blank leaderboard page. How do I connect my Itunes Connect leaderboard to my code, and how do I make the app such that it places your score on the leaderboard, as right now the leaderboard is empty.

Here is the code I used:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //check user is logged into GameCenter
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if ((viewController) != nil) {

            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }

    }

//display leaderboard
func showLeaderboard() {

    var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "MyLeaderboard"

    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)

}

//take leaderboard away
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

How do I connect my Itunes Connect leaderboard to the app, and what code do I use to upload one's score to the leaderboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` to your class:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
...
}
```

This is the code you need to use to authenticate the player:

```
func login() {
    println("Game Center Login Called")
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    // Handle the authentication
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(Home: UIViewController!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if Home != nil {
            println("Authentication is being processed.")
            self.presentViewController(Home, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            println("Player has been successfully authenticated.")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code you should use to show up the leaderboard:

```
func showLeaderboard() {

    var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "YOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID"
    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This code is needed when the user taps on "Done".

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can call the authentication method `login()` in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
login()
...
}
```

Show up the leaderboard when the user taps on a button

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    showLeaderboard()
}
```

If you want to submit the best score:

```
if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
                        println("I have submitted the score to Game Center")
                        let gkScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "Best_Score")
                        gkScore.value = Int64(bestScore)
                        GKScore.reportScores([gkScore], withCompletionHandler: ( { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
                            if (error != nil) {
                                // handle error
                                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription);
                            } else {
                                println("Score reported: \(gkScore.value)")
                            }
                        }))
                    }
```

Comment: Where in this code would I connect my iTunes Connect Leaderboard to the app? And where in this would I submit the users score to the leaderboard?

Comment: Please look accurately at my answer: `"YOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID"`. Updated the code with the score submission.

Comment: Glad to help! :) If you think my answer has solved your issue you can mark it as correct by ticking that the white icon to turn it green. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason, the leaderboard is coming up with the message, "No Scores". Why is that? Thank you for your fast responses.

Comment: Did you make sure to modify this line with your leaderboard ID?                         `let gkScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "Best_Score")`

Comment: I did. Could it be something to do with having no users? Except I would be counted as a user, because I have a sandbox account.

Comment: The sandbox accounts count as users. Did you use your own variable for the best score in this line of code, right? `gkScore.value = Int64(bestScore)`

Comment: I did. I used my NSUserDefault value for highscore: `Int64(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as Int!)`

Comment: Is the console printing this line of code? `println("Score reported: \(gkScore.value)")`

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't change any aspect of that.

Comment: Use this instead: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(bestScore, forKey: "highscore")}`

Comment: To load the best score you will have to use this code:  `// Load the Best Score
        highscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69560/discussion-between-cecexx-and-tdh).

Comment: What would I put in place of bestScore? My highscore variable is in GameScene, so I can't use it unless I use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as Int!`